# Does Disney now own Howard the Duck, and why?

Tags: production, copyright, disney, howard-the-duck

*Howard the Duck* is considered [one of the worst films of all time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_considered_the_worst#Howard_the_Duck_(1986)).  It was based on a Marvel Comics character, made into a movie by George Lucas in 1986.  The movie was a failure both critically and commercially.  It won four Golden Raspberry Awards and was nominated for three more.

Does Disney now own this cinematic detritus?

If so, from which subsidery they get the rights? Is it because they own Marvel Entertainment, which has Marvel Studios (a different Disney-owned subsidiary), or because they purchased Lucasfilm?

Related: [What was the reference in the post credit scene in Guardians of the Galaxy?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/23971/65120)

Answer (score 3):

Universal Studio's distributed the film both on its release and on all subsequent home video releases but the film was both produced by Lucasfilm Ltd and based on a Marvel property (it was the first Marvel character to receive a feature adaption).

I would imagine that they have any continuing property rights to the character outside of the original film release, which Disney would have acquired along with the acquisition of both Marvel Studios and (possibly?) Lucasfilm Ltd.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the OP was asking which one of those brought over Howard.  Was it Marvel or Lucas?  As such, this doesn't really answer the question.